# GIT Return back push

Tags: git

I have pushed my wrong commit into remote repository into new branch. Is a way back? Can I delete my branch and push new revision? What is the best way?

Thanks

Comment: I think this question could benefit from a simple text diagram of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the remote branch by typing:

```
git push origin :branch_name
```